# How to create Toggle binding from array of objects?

Tags: swift, swiftui

There are several useful questions on this topic, but all I've found either use deprecated syntax from earlier betas (e.g., BindableObject) or do not require a binding be passed (e.g., to a Toggle).

I want to create a list of Toggles that are bound to elements in an array. I've tried many methods, but the syntax is never corrrect. The version below most closely matches the answers to [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459727/why-an-observedobject-array-is-not-updated-in-my-swiftui-application).

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: String { self.name }
    var name: String
    var enabled: Bool
}

final class ItemSet: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item]

    init() {
        items = [
            Item(name: "aaa", enabled: true),
            Item(name: "bbb", enabled: false),
            Item(name: "ccc", enabled: true)
        ]
    }
}

var myItems = ItemSet()

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var items: ItemSet

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items.items) { item in
                Toggle(item.name, isOn: $item.enabled)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(items: myItems)
    }
}
```

The compiler error I get in Xcode 11.1 is:

> Use of unresolved identifier '$item'

on the line where Toggle is defined.

I was under the impression that each `Item` would itself need to be an `ObservableObject` with a `@Published var enabled: Bool` parameter, but I have not been able to get that working either, and all stackoverflow answers seems to say avoid making `Item` itself `ObservableObject`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe the issue here is using ForEach. Because `item` is a struct, it's a copy of that struct? The Landmarks example from Apple uses an index directly into the `items.items` array... likely for this reason.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing the property wrapper for `items` (which is a current value subject) with the binding parameter that a `Toggle` expects.  See corrected implementation with binding below:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Item: Identifiable {
  var isEnabled: Binding<Bool>
  var id: String { self.name }
  var name: String
  init(name: String, enabled enabledValue: Bool) {
    self.name = name
    let enabled = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(enabledValue)
    isEnabled = Binding<Bool>(
      get: { enabled.value },
      set: { enabled.value = $0}
    )
  }
}

final class ItemSet: ObservableObject {
  @Published var items: [Item]

  init() {
    items = [
      Item(name: "aaa", enabled: true),
      Item(name: "bbb", enabled: false),
      Item(name: "ccc", enabled: true)
    ]
  }
}

var myItems = ItemSet()

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var items: ItemSet

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(items.items) { item in
        Toggle(isOn: item.isEnabled, label: { Text (item.name) })
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView(items: myItems)
  }
}
```