# How to handle data and data models in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, list, swiftui, data-modeling

I am having trouble with the structure of my data for creating a `List` in `SwiftUI`. Before `SwiftUI` I created my data models and held this data in separated files. For example,

In my `UserModel.swift` :

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserModel: Equateable {

    var name: String
    var items = [ItemModel]()

    init(name: String, items: [ItemModel]? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        if let items = items {
            self.items = items
        }
    }
}
```

In my `ItemModel.swift` :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemModel: Equatable {
    var itemName: String
    var price: Double

    init(itemName: String, price: Double) {
        self.itemName = itemName
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

Then I had a separate class called `Data` that held this data.

In my `Data.swift` :

```
 import Foundation

class Data {
    static var userModels = [UserModel]()
    static var itemModels = [ItemModel]()
}
```

I would update the data by doing something like this in my `views`:

```
let user = UserModel(name: "Bob")
Data.userModels.append(user)
```

I'm having trouble populating a `List` from this framework in `SwiftUI`. I tried to make both of my model classes conform to `Identifiable` but that doesn't seem to help in updating the list. This is what I'm doing so far:

Updated `UserModel` :

```
struct UserModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()

    var name: String
    var items = [ItemModel]()

    init(id: UUID, name: String, items: [ItemModel]? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        if let items = items {
            self.items = items
        }
    }
}
```

Updated `ItemModel`:

```
struct ItemModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()

    var itemName: String
    var price: Double

    init(id: UUID, itemName: String, price: Double) {
        self.id = id
        self.itemName = itemName
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

And in my `ContentView.swift`

```
List (Data.userModels) { user in
    Text("\(user.name)")

}
```

But this does not update the `List` when I am running the app. (Btw I take input from `TextField`, append it to `Data.userModels`, and try to populate it in the `List` with no luck.)

Is there a different way I should be structuring my data and data models? Or am I just not using the proper syntax when creating the list? Sorry for the long question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to make your model class ObservableObject. Check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459727/why-an-observedobject-array-is-not-updated-in-my-swiftui-application) for example how this can be done.