# SwiftUI: How to change @Published object value. Changing a value of a published variable is not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm doing a page which consists of 5 Options with radio buttons. When we tap on an option the colour of the element should change. I'm fetching those options from API response. I'm using the MVVM model. I am attaching the code below.

What I'm struggling with is when I change a boolean value, it is not changing!!!

**View Model code**

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class DCListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var DCList = [DCViewModel]()

    init() {
        fetchDcs()
    }

    func fetchDcs() {
        ARMServices().getAllDc { (dcArr) in
            if let dcArr = dcArr {
                for dc in dcArr{
                    self.DCList.append(DCViewModel(dc: dc, isSelected: false))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class DCViewModel {
    var id = UUID()
    var dcStruct: DC
    var isSelected: Bool

    init(dc: DC, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.dcStruct = dc
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }

    var url: String {
        return self.dcStruct.url  ?? "empty URL"
    }

    var dc: String {
        return self.dcStruct.dc ?? "empty dc name"
    }
}
```

**View Page Code**

```
struct SelectTableView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

                VStack {
                    DCListView(dcList: self.dcListVM.DCList)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            .navigationBarTitle("Select the Data Centre")
        }
    }
}


struct DCListView: View{
    var dcList: [DCViewModel]

    init(dcList: [DCViewModel]) {
        self.dcList = dcList
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(self.dcList, id: \.id) { dc in
            Button(action: {
                print("Tapped")
                dc.isSelected.toggle()
            }){
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .stroke(dc.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected"): Color.init("border"))
                        .frame(height: 56)
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)

                    HStack {
                        Text(dc.dc)
                            .font(.custom("Montserrat", size: 16))
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .foregroundColor(dc.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected") : .white)
                            .padding()

                        Spacer()

                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .stroke(dc.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected") : Color("circleBorder"))
                                .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                                .padding()

                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                                .foregroundColor(dc.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected"): Color.clear)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The page looks like this]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Solution

Change `DCViewModel` to `struct`.

Or if you have to keep it as a `class`, make `DCViewModel` conform to `ObservableObject` , and keep a single reference in every single`View`. (which means you should subtract that row as a single `View`)

---

#### Explanation

@Published is a property wrapper that publishes change message only when the wrapped value has **been set**.

> The difference between value type and reference type: when you change a variable that holds a value type(struct), it has been set a new value actually. But when you change the value of a reference type(class), the variable that points to that object won't change.

That's why, in your case, when you add a new `DCViewModel` to the `Array`(value type), you are always setting a new value to that array, so `@Published` takes effect. However, the wrapped value is `DCViewModel`, which is a class(reference type). When you change `DCViewModel`'s value, the wrapped value's setter will not be called and `@Published` won't publish messages.

Comment: Thank you @ribilynn for explaining the scenario. This works well.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options.

1. Change `DCViewModel` `class` to `struct`.
2. Manually make `DCListViewModel` `class` to publish.

See [@kontiki 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57459844/12353435)

#### Change `DCViewModel` `class` to `struct`.

```swift
struct DCViewModel {
    var id: UUID
    var dcStruct: DC
    var isSelected: Bool

    init(dc: DC, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.dcStruct = dc
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }

    var url: String {
        return self.dcStruct.url  ?? "empty URL"
    }

    var dc: String {
        return self.dcStruct.dc ?? "empty dc name"
    }
}

struct SelectTableView: View {
    // dcListVM missed
    // I assume superview of SelectTableView exist.
    @ObservedObject var dcListVM: DCListViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    DCListView(dcList: $dcListVM.DCList)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            .navigationBarTitle("Select the Data Centre")
        }
    }
}

struct DCListView: View{
    @Binding var dcList: [DCViewModel] // Use @Binding for two-way binding

    var body: some View {
        // You can't use `ForEach(data: self.dcList, id: \.id ) { dc in`
        // Because `dc` is immutable

        ForEach(0..<self.dcList.count) { dc in
            Button(action: {
                print("Tapped")
                self.dcList[dc].isSelected.toggle()
            }){
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .stroke(self.dcList[dc].isSelected ? Color.red: Color.black)
                        .frame(height: 56)
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)

                    HStack {
                        Text(self.dcList[dc].dc)
                            .font(.system(size: 16))
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .foregroundColor(self.dcList[dc].isSelected ? Color.red : Color.black)
                            .padding()

                        Spacer()

                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .stroke(self.dcList[dc].isSelected ? Color.red : Color.black)
                                .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                                .padding()

                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                                .foregroundColor(self.dcList[dc].isSelected ? Color.red: Color.clear)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Manually make instance of `DCListViewModel` to publish.

```swift
struct SelectTableView: View {
    // dcListVM missed
    // I assume superview of SelectTableView exist.
    var dcListVM: DCListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

                VStack {
                    DCListView(dcList: self.dcListVM) // DCListViewModel instead of [DCViewModel]
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            .navigationBarTitle("Select the Data Centre")
        }
    }
}


struct DCListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dcListVM: DCViewModel // DCListViewModel instead of [DCViewModel]

    // See "Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types" in docs.swift.org
    // init(dcListVM: DCViewModel) {
    //     self.dcList = dcList
    // }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(self.dcList.DCList, id: \.id) { dc in
            Button(action: {
                print("Tapped")
                dc.isSelected.toggle()
                self.dcList.objectWillChange.send()  // Manually make dcList to publish
            }){
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .stroke(dc.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected"): Color.init("border"))
                        .frame(height: 56)
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)

                    HStack {
                        Text(dc.dc)
                            .font(.custom("Montserrat", size: 16))
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .foregroundColor(dc.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected") : .white)
                            .padding()

                        Spacer()

                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .stroke(dc.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected") : Color("circleBorder"))
                                .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                                .padding()

                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                                .foregroundColor(dc.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected"): Color.clear)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just "giving" the copy of dclist to your views, so the view does not know what changes happens. Add @binding to your views to your variable dclist.