# SwiftUI cant bind injected value

Tags: ios, swift, binding, swiftui

I found [this demo project](https://github.com/nalexn/clean-architecture-swiftui) that shows how to use clean swift with swiftU, so I tried to do something like this on my own. I came up with problem while using Core Data. As clean swift architecture only one source (appState in my case) can pass data to view. So I created injection container, it has **interactor** and **appState**.
Container:

```
struct DIContainer: EnvironmentKey {

    @ObservedObject var appState: AppState
    let interactors: Interactors

    init(appState: AppState, interactors: Interactors) {
        self.appState = appState
        self.interactors = interactors
    }
```

```
class AppState: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    var userData = UserData()
}

extension AppState {
    class UserData: ObservableObject, Equatable {
        @Published var places:[Place] = []
}
```

And I inject enviroment like this:

```
@Environment(\.injected) private var injected: DIContainer
```

And finally view that uses it:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(injected.$appState.userData.places.wrappedValue){ place in
                        PlaceRow(place: place)
                    }
....
```

Problem is that even array is loade, view doesnt react to that. It refreshes only when i navigate to other view. Also, when I delete or add new elements to array, view has no changes. 
If you can give me some ideas it would be nice. 
I googled for 4 days, everything I find is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're injecting the `DIContainer` into your `View` like this:

```
@Environment(\.injected) private var injected: DIContainer
```

remember that your `View` will not refresh when the `DIContainer` properties will change. You have to manually observe them.

You can try one of these solutions:

**1)** Subscribe to the `AppState` properties' changes in `.onReceive`:

```
@Environment(\.injected) private var injected: DIContainer

var body: some View {
    NavigationView { ... }
        .onReceive(injected.appState.userData.$places) { places in
            // do something with places, 
            // eg. assign to a @State variable to be used in a `ForEach` loop...
        }
}
```

**2)** Inject the `UserData` directly as an `@EnvironmentObject`:

```
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

ContentView().environmentObject(container.appState.userData)
```

As the `UserData` is an `ObservableObject` it will change whenever any of its `@Published` properties (eg. `places`) is modified.

**3)** Subscribe to the `AppState`/`UserData` in the `ViewModel` and observe the only the `ViewModel` in your `View`.

The more detailed explanation can be found in [this](https://github.com/nalexn/clean-architecture-swiftui/tree/3f5715990e43337c79743b8fb08c5131c28ff474) version of the same demo project you linked in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First solution partly works, but thing is, when I update some object in array, view doesnt change unless I add new item to array.

Comment: Yes, that's because you observe `places` and not it's items. If you change an item, the `places` variable remains unchanged. It's the same as the problem with the `DIContainer` which I explained above.

Comment: I honestly cant get it. I did exactly how you showed in first solution above. Also I added  `self.objectWillChange.send()` to `willSet` of my `places` in userData class. What should I do to observe `places` and not it's items??

Comment: One of the solutions is to make `Place` a *struct* instead of a *class*. You can find more detailed explanation in the answer to this question: [Why an ObservedObject array is not updated in my SwiftUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459727/why-an-observedobject-array-is-not-updated-in-my-swiftui-application)