# How to observe change in @StateObject in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am having property with @StateObject, I am trying to observe change in viewmodel, I am able to print correct result but can not able to show on screen as view is not refreshing.

Tried using binding but not worked because of @StateObject

```
import SwiftUI
struct AbcView: View {

    @StateObject var abcViewModel: AbcViewModel

    init(abcViewModel: AbcViewModel) {
        self._abcViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: abcViewModel)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                ScrollView {
                    Text("some txt")
                }
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        TopView(content: classViews(data: $abcViewModel.somedata, abcViewModel: abcViewModel))
                        Spacer()
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

func classViews(data: Binding<[SomeData]>, abcViewModel: AbcViewModel) -> [AnyView] {
    var views: [AnyView] = []

    for element in data {
        views.append(
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                HStack {
                    print("\(abcViewModel.title(Id: Int(element.dataId.wrappedValue ?? "")) )") // printing correct value
                    Text(abcViewModel.title(Id: Int(element.dataId.wrappedValue ?? ""))) // want to observe change here
                }
            }
                .convertToAnyView())
    }
    return views
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is an ObservedObject array not updated in my SwiftUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459727/why-is-an-observedobject-array-not-updated-in-my-swiftui-application)

Comment: @New iOS Dev, did my answer provide solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you are injecting your `AbcViewModel` into `AbcView` you should use `@ObserverdObject` instead of `@StateObject` , [full explanation here](https://swiftuipropertywrappers.com/) Also you should conform tour `AbcViewModel` to `ObservableObject` and make your desired property `@Published` if you want to trigger the change in `View` . Here is simplified code example:

1. Making `AbcViewModel` observable:

   ```
   class AbcViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dataID: String = "" //by changing the @Published   proprty you trigger change in View using it
   }
   ```
2. store `AbcViewModel` as `@ObserverdObject`:

   ```
   struct AbcView: View {
    @ObservedObject var abcViewModel: AbcViewModel

    init(abcViewModel: AbcViewModel) {
        self.abcViewModel = abcViewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
       //...
    }
   }
   ```
3. If you now use your `AbcViewModel` `dataID` property anywhere in the project, and you change its value, the property will publish the change and your `View` (struct) will be rebuilded. Use the same pattern for creating `TopView` and assigning `AbcViewModel` to it the same way.