# SwiftUI view not being refreshed when Published object changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, objectmapper, property-wrapper-published

In my view model I have this property and method:

```
@Published var cats: [Cat] = [] //this gets populated later
```

When I update one of the cats as such:

```
func updateCatQuantity(_ cat:Cat, qty: Int) {
    if let index = cats(of: cat) {
        cats[index].quantity = qty
    }
}
```

The view does not get refreshed. `didSet` on `cats` does not get called. I think it has something to do with the fact that `Cat` is a class instead of a struct. Here's how it's defined:

```
class Cat: BaseMapperModel, Identifiable, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Cat, rhs: Cat) -> Bool {
       return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
    }

    var id = UUID()

    var title: String = ""
    var quantity: Int = 0

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        title <- map["title"]
        quantity <- map["qty"]
    }
}
```

How can I get the view to refresh when the quantity of a cat is changed?

Comment: In this scenario with a `@published` array, I have got it working with Cat being a `struct` - any change to a property makes a whole new struct. You might need to use mutating functions with variables within the Cat struct. Classes don’t update in the way you expect as the array holds references, which don’t change.

Comment: If you have difficulty updating a single instance of a Cat struct (based on above comment), you can just set the `cats[index]` equal to a new instance of Cat with the relevant property changed.

Comment: If you want to use a class like this, you will need to call objectWillChange manually on your ObservableObject. Better to switch to a struct, which SwiftUI is built to work with.

Comment: I appreciate the comments, but maybe a full answer post could help? For example I tried setting cats[index] to a new instance but it didn't work.    `cats[index] = Cat.init(JSON: ["title": cat.title, "quantity": qty])!`
And trying to change Cat to a struct throws a lot of errors...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is an ObservedObject array not updated in my SwiftUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459727/why-is-an-observedobject-array-not-updated-in-my-swiftui-application)

Comment: Well, yes, I knew that converting the class to a struct was a potential solution. Due to other constraints that wasn't easy, but it's eventually what I did because I couldn't get it to work as a class.

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is a view model already you don't need another one

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 issues

1. `@Published` only triggers a refresh when the "value" changes. Changing a variable in a `class` is not considered a "value" change.

Switching to a `struct` is the "easy" change.

```
struct Cat: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()

    var title: String = ""
    var quantity: Int = 0
}
```

But issue #2 is a bigger deal. By overriding `Hashable` you are telling SwiftUI to only trigger `View` reloads when the `id` changes.

To observe a `class` in iOS 13-16 the object has to conform to `ObservableObject` and be wrapped with `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject`, appropriately at every level you want to see changes.

```
class Cat: Identifiable, Hashable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()

    @Published var title: String = ""
    @Published var quantity: Int = 0

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(title)
        hasher.combine(quantity)
    }
    static func == (lhs: Cat, rhs: Cat) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id 
        && lhs.title == rhs.title
        && lhs.quantity == rhs.quantity
    }
}
```

in iOS 17+ you can use `@Observable` instead of an `ObservableObject` with `@State` and `@Bindable` appropriately.

```
@Observable
class Cat: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()

    var title: String = ""
    var quantity: Int = 0
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(title)
        hasher.combine(quantity)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Cat, rhs: Cat) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
        && lhs.title == rhs.title
        && lhs.quantity == rhs.quantity
    }
}
```

Comment: Dang, this looked promising. I'm supporting 16+ so I tried your `ObservableObject` suggestion (and updated the `hash` and `==` functions). Still no luck. The view still only updates once I tap some other button.

Comment: @soleil make sure you are using a wrapper at every level like I mentioned. SwiftUI can’t detect changes without them. StateObject to initialize and ObservedObject to pass around. At every level using subviews if necessary.

Comment: what should the wrapper look like? Is `@Published var cats: [Cat] = []` not correct? Do I need a wrapper on the view model or something? Currently I have `class MyViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Hashable`

Comment: Published can’t observe ObservableObjects (issue 1 above), the View needs a wrapper https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject

Comment: This is so confusing. If I change it to `@ObservedObject var cats: [Cat] = []`, I get `Generic struct 'ObservedObject' requires that '[Cat]' conform to 'ObservableObject'`. But `Cat` already does.

Comment: In THE View, each cat needs a wrapper.  @soleil not the array the array is fine.

Comment: How would I do that? In the view I have this: `ForEach(viewModel.cats.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    let cat = viewModel.cats[index]
    ...do stuff with cat, including updating quantity when the user selects a new value in a sheet`

Comment: @soleil with a subview. Also, indices are unsafe with SwiftUI you should not use them

Comment: I guess I don't understand. The main view already has `@ObservedObject var viewModel: MyViewModel` so I don't see how making another subclass with that same wrapper will help anything :(

Comment: @soleil NP but this is the answer. This is how SwiftUI is setup every ObservableObject needs their own, it is a SwiftUI requirement until iOS 17 with the new macro

Comment: @soleil I just notice you said another subclass, you aren’t creating a subclass to get it to work, cat is the ObservableObject. You need another View which is a struct.